# Master slave replication with different mysql version is on both slave and master

Tags: mysql-5.5, linux, mysql-5.7, aws, master-slave-replication

Currently, we have MySQL master-slave replication. Both master and slave servers have Mysql 5.5 Currently I need to add one more Master server having version 5.7.

**Is it possible to add Multiple masters to a single slave server?**

> One master and slave is having Mysql 5.5 and new Mysql server is 5.7

**Is it possible to configure Master-slave replication with different MySQL version?**

Answer (score 0):

When replicating, the master version must be the same or less than the version on the slave. If this isn't the case, the master may inject binary log messages the slave doesn't understand.

The master version / slave version should stay between on major version. So a 5.6 master is ok to a 5.5 slave but a 5.7 slave is too much, there may be deprecated messages in 5.6 that a 5.7 slave will not understand.

Multiple masters are possible with [5.7 multi source replication.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html).

Comment: My situation is currently the master version and slave version is same (5.5). Planning to add one more master with version 5.7 for the same slave. How to do this? multi-master is possible in 5.5 version (slave server is 5.5)

Comment: Sorry, you can't get new features on old versions. The slave version has to be 5.7 to have multi master capabilities. You'll need to update versions, one major version at a time, slave before master, until 5.7 to get the new features you want.